# How to show popup menu in current place

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, popup

I have recycler view with click listener.when I clicked on view it shows popup menu. The problem is that popup menu is showing on the top-left corner of clicked item. Is it possible to show popup menu at the point where was clicked?

```
private fun showPopup(view: View, item: BaseModel) {
        val popup = PopupMenu(context!!, view, Gravity.CENTER)
        popup.inflate(R.menu.docs_menu)
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener({ itemMenu: MenuItem ->

            when (itemMenu.itemId) {
                R.id.del -> {
                    if (item is AutoRecord){
                        presenter.onAutoDelete(item)
                    } else{
                        presenter.onDriverDelete(item as DriverRecord)
                    }
                }
            }
            true
        })

        popup.show()
    }
```

Usage:

```
driverAdapter.onLongItemClick = { item, view ->
    showPopup(view, item)
}
```

Comment: add some code for reference

Comment: plz paste code snippet of show popup menu.

Comment: @JunJieWang added

Comment: use popup window

Comment: @Quicklearner Could you explain why I should use popup window instead of popup? I want to show context menu